# jump to the previous 'x' character in bash

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>Ctrl + ]</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> shortcut lets you jump to the next "x" character in the bash terminal (much like 'fx' in vim).

What would be the shortcut to jump to the previous "x" character (much like 'Fx' in vim)?

I found out that <kbd>Alt + Ctrl + ]</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> is supposed to do that, but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The readline function `character-search` is by default bound to <kbd>Ctrl+]</kbd>.  This is what you mention in you question:

```
$ bind -q character-search
character-search can be invoked via "\C-]".
```

The function `character-search-backward` is bound to <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl+]</kbd>:

```
$ bind -q character-search-backward
character-search-backward can be invoked via "\M-\C-]".
```

`\M` is <kbd>Esc</kbd>, not <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

So, to search backwards for `x`, use <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl+]</kbd> followed by <kbd>x</kbd>.

Since <kbd>Esc</kbd> is the same as <kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd>, it may be quicker to type <kbd>Ctrl+[</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl+]</kbd> to search backwards for a particular character.

Obviously, in Vi command line editing mode (`set -o vi`), you could just use <kbd>f</kbd> and <kbd>F</kbd> in normal mode, as in Vi, which you seem to be familiar with.

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted. An addendum: (At least) Xterm does send an Esc-prefixed keycode on Alt combinations if `metaSendsEscape` is `true` in the X-resources file.

Comment: perfect answer, thank you for posting how this setting can be found with 'bind' command